# Como quitar de un ps aux el <s>

Tags: html, bash, apache2

pues a ver, lo que intento es crear una web donde me muestre todos los procesos del servidor para poder matar el que quiera. El problema surge cuando el proceso se encuentra en un estado S<s, ya que cuando la abre el navegador, lo interpreta como subrayado ya que es un tag de html.
No se como quitarlo... lo intento con awk pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

mi codigo queda algo parecido a
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intento hacer diversos sed, pero no consigo hacerlo, incluso me he creado un archivo aux.txt donde envio el ps y tampoco.
Alguna sugerencia????

Comment: Deberías codificar la salida, así no tendrás ese problema. Es lo que se me ocurre. Podrías probar [esto](https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/5a90c49e0976aadfe0726a847ce58736), que tal vez te ayude. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes acceso a ese servidor y puedes instalar el comando `recode` esto podria funcionarte:

```
ps aux | recode utf8..html
```

Al menos en mi ubuntu me ha funcionado. [Aquí tienes un enlace a su documentación](https://linux.die.net/man/1/recode) (en ingles) y tiene página `info`, por lo tanto una vez instalado puedes acceder a mucha más informacion escribiendo `info recode` en el terminal (donde encontrarás la sintaxis que estoy usando de dos puntos `..`).

### Actualización

El OP ha usado esta respuesta en su script, el cual ha terminado implementado así (con su código corregido pues también lo tenia mal debido a las comillas):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Procesos Activos y Matar</title>
      </head>
      <body><h1>Procesos Activos</h1>
      <pre>
"
ps aux | recode utf8..html
echo -e '
       </pre>
       <form action="./kill.sh" method="POST" ENCTYPO="text/plain">
       <input type="text" name="pid"
       <br>
       <input type>"submit" value="Matar Proces">
       </form>
       <button><a href="practica1.sh" title="volver">Voler</a></button>
       </body>
</html>
'
```

Comment: Me funcionó así, lo que hice fué :ps aux |recode utf8..html >

Comment: Para aprender a aceptar respuestas válidas visita este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200).  Es importante tambien para la comunidad que inviertas dos minutos en hacer el [tour] para aprender bien el funcionamiento de este sitio, y aprendas el sistema de preguntas/respuestas y votos/aceptaciones, y de paso te regalan una medalla!

Comment: Pues como tú bien dices no hace falta mandarlo a ningún txt, sólo he tenido que modificar el código en html con un <pre>, para que quedara bonito, y ya está. Anteriormente lo había hecho porque así le agregaba un do while, con leer linea y hacerle un  <br> para que se viera bien, pero de esta manera no hace falta y queda hasta mejor.
``` echo -e <pre>
  ps aux | recode utf8..html
  echo -e  </pre>```

Comment: no se como dar formato en los comentarios.... jajajajajaja llevo un buen rato y no lo consigo...

Comment: jeje, es que en los comentarios no hace falta poner tres tildes invertidas, se hace con una solo (al principio y al final), y si son varias lineas nada, te lo pondra siempre en una solo, pero te he entendido, es lo que yo habia propuesto de hecho, por lo tanto no voy a variar mi respuesta, la cual se refería solo a la linea del `ps`, el resto no lo alteraba y no hacia falta ponerlo otra vez en la respuesta (porque implicaba teclearlo todo, y como lo habias puesto en una imagen me daba pereza hacerlo :-P)

Answer (score 3):

En el `ps aux` tendrás que añadir lo siguiente:

```
ps aux | sed 's/<s//g' > aux.txt
```

De esta forma, me funcionó! espero que te sirva.